# Lagrange multipliers of $f(x,y,z,w) =x+y-z-w$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am really spinning around with this kind of exercises:

> Find global maxima/minima of $f(x,y,z,w) =x+y-z-w$ in $A=\{ (x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4: x^2+y^2 = 1 \wedge w = x+z \}$.

Moving the conditions of $A$ around:
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2-1=0 \\
x+z-w = 0
\end{cases}

Then, adding both terms: $x^2+y^2-1+x+z-w = 0$

Let $g(x,y,z,w) = x^2+y^2-1+x+z-w$

$\Rightarrow$

- $g_x = 2x+1$
- $g_y  = 2y$
- $g_z = 1$
- $g_w = -1$

Using Lagrange multipliers I get to this:
\begin{cases}
f_z = -1 = \lambda g_z = \lambda 1 \\
f_w = -1 = \lambda g_w = \lambda (-1) \\
\end{cases}

Providing that the operations are correct, would this prove that $f$ doesn't achieve any maxima nor minima inside of the set $A$ according to Lagrange Multiplier's theorem? Is that possible? Is there some kind of a conflict with the restrictions?

Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Careful in your procedure. If $g_1 = c_1$ and $g_2 = c_2$ are constraints, then don't combine them into one equation $g = g_1 + g_2$ as you have done here. Rather, the Lagrange equations are

$$\nabla(f + \lambda_1 g_1 + \lambda_2 g_2) = 0$$

Comment: I know that would be the equations according to the definition, but is it totally incorrect to simplify as I did by combining the constrains?

Comment: Yes. To give an example $f(x,y) = xy, g_1(x,y) = x = 0, g_2(x,y) = y = 0$. If you optimize instead on $g = g_1 + g_2$ you'll get completely different answers. Using $g_1 + g_2$ significantly changes the nature of the constraint.

Comment: And the same goes if both constraints depend on different variables? (For example $g1(x,y)$ and $g2(z,w)$.)

Comment: Yes, as they did in my example and in yours. There's only one point for which $x = 0$ and $y = 0$, but infinitely many for which $x + y = 0$. It's hard to visualize $(x,y,z,w)$ space. But I hope you can see that there are infinitely more points that satisfy the sum of your two constraints than satisfy them both separately.

Comment: That has helped a lot. Thanks a bunch, Simon!

Comment: Lagrange multipliers only apply at an extrema. There are no extrema here, so Lagrange multipliers are irrelevant.

Comment: Absolutely, that observation is the most germane for this problem. Even so, this discussion on how to treat constraints was still important in general.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always check that the extrema exist.

In this case, we can take $x=1,y=0$ and let $w=x+z=1+z$. Then the point
$(1,0, z, 1+z)$ satisfies the constraints and
we have $f(1,0, z, 1+z) = 1+0-z-(1+z) = -2z$.

Hence by choosing $z$ appropriately, $f$ can be as large or as small as you want, hence there are no global extrema.

In fact, more generally, if $(x,y,z,w)$ satisfies the constraints, then so does
$(x,y,z+h,w+h)$, and $f(x,y,z+h,w+h) = f(x,y,z,w)-2h$, hence there are no local extrema.

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll definitely keep it in mind for the future.
This behavior happens because $x$ and $y$ are bounded, but $w$ and $z$ aren't, right?

Comment: Well, $x,y$ are somewhat irrelevant other than the circle constraint being satisfied. The main reason is that there is a direction that you can move in ($h=\pm (0,0,1,1)$) that keeps the constraints satisfied and for which the cost is unbounded above and below.

Comment: I see. I have to learn to analyze the little details of how each variable interacts in the big picture... Thank you very much, copper.hat.